# Private prerender server wont render angularjs scripts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, phantomjs, prerender

I want to create prerendered pages for search engines. I am using MEAN stack (Mongo,Express,Angular,Node). I decided to create my own [prerender](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) server.

I have deployed it to Heroku with following commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

And now I have my own prerender server, that work if you add `/https://www.google.com` or `/http://stackoverflow.com`.

But it doesn't work with my angular app, that is also deployed on heroku.
I can write http://mysites.com/?_escaped_fragment_=thinkpad/t-400
**And get bunch of `{{not rendered angular}}`**

*I have `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` in my `index.html`.*

I have

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'prerender-server-url'));
```

in my `express.js`.

**How can I make it work?**

Comment: When you go to http://mysites.com/?_escaped_fragment_=thinkpad/t-400 are you seeing console output if you do `heroku logs --tail` on your Prerender server?

Comment: @Prerender.io `[0m at=info method=GET path="/http://mysites.com/?_escaped_fragment_=" host=desolate-earth-****.herokuapp.com request_id=f0f90b8d-be83-****-92fd-4886df243b4c fwd="54.205.***.95" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1555ms status=200 bytes=4136`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that you are not using newer ES6 features that are supported by the browsers, but not yet supported by `prerender` JS engine.